# Need to map with multiple columns with rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have columns like

U1,U2,U3,U4 IN ONE TABLE A which has values

```
1  3  5  5
3  4  8  9
```

and another table B which has a column with values

```
column_map
U1
U2
U4
U1
```

now I need to map the table B with table A columns and get the value

Comment: What do you mean "map the table"? What is your expected output?

Comment: column_map is the column name and U1, U2 are rows of the table. I need to match rows U1 U2 with another table which has the same column as U1 U2 i need to get the values the table. Expected output will be                      
U1   U2   U4
1    3     5
3    4     9

Comment: A SQL query has a pre-defined set of columns, unless you are using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Can you roughly make a sample query on how to do that, those are static columns and just 5 columns only

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this dynamically in pl/sql although I don't personally know how. Pending a better answer that uses a dynamic approach you could at least use the following, although it would be annoying to write if the table has a lot of columns:

```
select 'U1' as column_map, u1 as col_value from tablea union all
select 'U2', u2 from tablea union all
select 'U3', u3 from tablea union all
select 'U4', u4 from tablea
```

.... and so on until you've selected all of the columns.